# Flutter data to Json

Tags: firebase, flutter

How can I transfer QuerySnapshot object data from Firebase to JSON string?

Do I need to use

```
 json.decode(qs)?
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1, Recommend you to use pkg: json_annotation to define model.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

2, When define model, let using bellow annotation for your model :

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part 'agent.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(
    anyMap: true
)
class Agent {

  @JsonKey(
    ignore: true
  )
  String id;

  String name;

  String avatar;

  String email;

  String phone;

  String team;

  String password;


  Agent(this.name, this.avatar, this.email, this.phone, this.team, this.password);

  factory Agent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AgentFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AgentToJson(this);
}
```

3, Parser model with documentSnapshot:

```
Agent.fromJson(documentSnapshot.data)
```